# Angularjs Spring controller form submission

Tags: java, angularjs, forms, spring-mvc

Java - spring controller - Angularjs form submission

Problem is with `"@RequestBody OfferForm data"` when i submit form i get error "404 bad request" but when i replace OfferForm bean with String object it works fine and display form data in json format.

any help appreciated.

Following is my angularjs function code

```
$scope.submitOffer = function() {
                      alert('submitOffer')
                    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/offer/submitOffer', data: $scope.formData}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.successMsg = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if(status == 400) {
                             $scope.errMessages = data;
                        } else {
                            alert('Unexpected server error.');
                        }

                    });         
                };
```

Following is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="offer")
public class OfferController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitOffer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<?> postForm(@RequestBody OfferForm data) {

        System.out.println(data);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Offer Created", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Following is my java bean

```
public class OfferForm {

    private String offerType;
    private String offerTitle;


    public String getOfferType() {
        return offerType;
    }
    public void setOfferType(String offerType) {
        this.offerType = offerType;
    }
    public String getOfferTitle() {
        return offerTitle;
    }
    public void setOfferTitle(String offerTitle) {
        this.offerTitle = offerTitle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show us what is `$scope.formData` ? It should be an object with at most two properties of type string: `offerType` and `offerTitle`. I think you have more properties than expected, thus the bad request

Comment: yes you are correct. i added all properties and it stopped giving me bad req error.

Comment: if you write above comment as answer i will accept it as points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scope.formData` object has more property than expected by the webservice.

You should provide to your webservice an object which has at most two properties of type string: `offerType` and `offerTitle`.
I think you currently have more properties than expected or you don't have the correct type, thus the bad request exception.

You could do something like that in your javascript, given that the two properties are a string:

```
$scope.submitOffer = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/offer/submitOffer',
        data: {
            offerType: $scope.formData.offerType,
            offerTitle: $scope.formData.offerTitle
        }
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.successMsg = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == 400) {
            $scope.errMessages = data;
        } else {
            alert('Unexpected server error.');
        }

    });
};
```